# How to break a long sentence in correct places in IE

Tags: html, css

I have to display really long sentences in a paragraph in a div. Couple of things I have to take care for this situation. 1. The lines should not go out of bound 2. The wrapping/breaking of the sentence should happen at the appropriate places, such as spaces between words. The following CSS works really well in Chrome. The code is from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/ with a minor modification.

```
 .handle-long-sentence{
     white-space: normal;

     overflow-wrap: break-word;
     word-wrap: break-word;

     -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-word;

    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;

  }
```

In IE11, the paragraph is displayed as flush with the word breaking randomly at various places.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xfdt2s5/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the CSS which worked in all three major browsers

```
.handle-long-sentence{
   white-space:normal;
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */ 
   -ms-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -o-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
}
```

This puts an hyphen in IE whenever a word is broken. In Chrome and Firefox, no word is broken and the space between words is used for word wrapping.